# Cannot add viewport Unreal C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to add a blueprint viewport through c++.
I keep getting errors that there is no overloaded instance for function
CreateWidget even though I've been following this
https://wiki.unrealengine.com/UMG,_Referencing_UMG_Widgets_in_Code

// HUD.h

```
// Copyright 1998-2018 Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

#pragma once 

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/HUD.h"
#include "ZombieHUD.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class AZombieHUD : public AHUD
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    AZombieHUD();

    /** Primary draw call for the HUD */
    virtual void DrawHUD() override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Widgets")
    TSubclassOf<class UUserWidget> wCrossHairWidget;

    UUserWidget* CrossHairWidget;

private:
    /** Crosshair asset pointer */
    class UTexture2D* CrosshairTex;

};
```

// HUD.cpp

```
// imports
#include "ZombieHUD.h"
#include "Engine/Canvas.h"
#include "Engine/Texture2D.h"
#include "TextureResource.h"
#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
#include "CanvasItem.h"
#include "UObject/ConstructorHelpers.h"

...

void AZombieHUD::DrawHUD()
{
    Super::DrawHUD();
    if (wCrossHairWidget) {

        auto name = FName(TEXT("CH"));
        CrossHairWidget = CreateWidget<UUserWidget>(this, wCrossHairWidget, name);
        if (CrossHairWidget)
        {
            CrossHairWidget>AddToViewport();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `UCLASS()
class AZombieHUD : public AHUD` - that looks weird. What does `UCLASS()` do there?

Comment: It came generated with the file

Comment: That may be so, but you should still know what it does...

Comment: I don't think the errors I'm getting are related to that.

Comment: Probably not. But I *personally* wouldn't like compiling code I didn't fully understand, and that just looks weird, so I would investigate. But never mind..

Comment: `UCLASS()` is a no-op; it’s used to implement reflection to display data in the editor. There is a special parser that looks through head files to identify classes, functions, and other constructs, once identified a clean name for them can be displayed within the primary editor. https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/unreal-property-system-reflection

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a AHUD cannot be the owner of a UUserWidget.

I've actually checked the [source code of AHUD](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/7d9919ac7bfd80b7483012eab342cb427d60e8c9/Engine/Source/Runtime/UMG/Public/Blueprint/UserWidget.h#L1421), that states that the valid owners of a UUserWidget can be of types:

- UWidget
- UWidgetTree
- APlayerController
- UGameInstance
- UWorld

So can you try something like this instead?

```
CrossHairWidget = CreateWidget<UUserWidget>(GetGameInstance(), wCrossHairWidget, name);
```

Hope that helps!